# How to know which version of CrafterCMS I am using?

Tags: content-management-system, crafter-cms

Is there a way to know the crafter version from Studio Admin Console/Dashboard?

I am running `CrafterCMS 3.0` on my local. But from the content admin's point of view, is there any way to know the exact version/build I am using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a feature being added in support of this. It's under Help > About, but it's not there yet.

You can track progress on the feature here: https://github.com/craftercms/craftercms/issues/813

And here for the UI: https://github.com/craftercms/craftercms/issues/711

Answer (score 6):

You can also try http://localhost:8080/studio/api/1/services/getInfo.json that will give you something like this:

`{"version":"3.0.0-SNAPSHOT","id":"33ed8125aa029a8170ed11d9cee62b802f45cd38","uiId":"f5318d804d51eea2501fdf1bc832af4c2ba5e30a","buildDate":"2017-05-09T10:38:21-06:00"}`

Note this also work for 2.5.x (since 2.5.6)

Comment: This is great. Works for now until we have the feature implemented. For my local installation I get uiID=unknown. what does that indicate?